# display of mysql calendar per months

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I'm am developing a website featuring a vacancy calendar connected to a database. I have managed to create the table that lists every single day from 2012-10-01 to 2030 with the following fields:

```
MyTable
-----------                 
 -dt date                       
 -mid smallint (ID for each month)  
 -y smallint (year)         
 -m tinyint (month)         
 -d tinyint (day)                   
 -dw tinyint (day of week)          
 -monthName varchar             
 -isVacant binary   
 -isWeekday  binary
```

I would like to display this data on the website showing each month (mid) in a row, showing each day and whether they are vacant or occupied. I need to basically turn data from rows into columns.

I have looked for a query to do that but nothing has worked so far. I have tried to rewrite examples of pivot query but I don't seem to be getting the syntax right. Could anyone help me with this?

here is what the stuff looks like:
[mysql calendar table](http://www.mathieuleguet.com/display/db-view.html) -
[html table](http://www.mathieuleguet.com/display/final-table.html)

Comment: Can you show the queries you have tried and what they do wrong?

Comment: can you post some sample data ans then the expected result?

Comment: have just edited the question with links to data sample and the result I wish.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to get the data into single rows in the mysql query? I'd just pull the data into php, one row per day, and use php to arrange the data however I want. There probably is a mysql solution, but I don't think it's worth the effort. Just loop through the days, populating your array as you go.

Comment: I'm not so experienced with writing such php as yet but I'll investigate in that direction for sure, thanks for the advice.

Comment: It's easy. `foreach($rows as $row) {(get the month and day here) $array[$month][$day]=value;}`. The specifics depend on how you're accessing the database and what exactly you're planning to do with the data, but that's all extremely basic stuff. Unless you've got a library doing the work for you, there's nothing in there that you wouldn't have to know to do any kind of database access at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think this is what you want to get. Could've been better if you supplied table data and result sample:

```
select m, (case d when 1 then isVacant),  (case d when 2 then isVacant), 
 (case d when 3 then isVacant), ..... 
from MyTable
group by m
order by m
```

**EDIT :**  Have a look at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ce37/1)
Note that I created isVacant column as integer typed field.

Comment: here is what I get:   #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '),  (case d when 2 then isVacant),  (case d when 3 then isVacant) from tblcal' at line 1

Comment: @Mat paste some data from your table, and also describe the result you desire

Comment: this damn site won't let me post screenshots as I've no reputation and I don't understand how to write tables in my question. Would you edit my question with screenshots if I emailed them to you?

Comment: sorry but I can't see any address on your profile. would you mail me at mathieuleguet@yahoo.ie so I can reply? thanks a million